# Operating with hex-values doesn't work with hex-function

Tags: python

1) I have a little problem while operating with hex-values. Why is `sendValue(hex(12289))` leading to an error (aborting script), while `sendValue(0x3001)` works?

```
def sendValue(value):
    for i in range(16):
        if (value & 0x8000):
            print "1" # later this bit will be sent to a LC
        else:
            print "0" # later this bit will be sent to a LC
        value <<= 1 # corrected this

def main():
    sendValue(0x3001)
    sendValue(hex(12289))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

2) I expected the output

```
0
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
```

But I just get `0`

Comment: It is because `hex(12289)` returns a `string` and you are comparing it with a `number` in `if`. So it throws an error.

Comment: You don't use `i` anywhere in the loop. You are doing `value & 0x8000` 16 times.

Comment: @PrerakSola: How do I convert the string to a (hex)number?

Comment: `int("0x3001", 16)` will convert your hex string to integer.

Comment: In future, if you post code that generates an error message _please_ paste the _full_ error message into a code block in your question, starting from the `Traceback (most recent call last):` line.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Sorry. I will do that in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sendValue()` function just prints the most significant bit of the number 16 times. You need to scan through each of the bits. Eg,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def sendValue(value):
    print hex(value),

    for i in range(16):
        if (value & 0x8000):
            print "1",
        else:
            print "0",

        #Right-shift value to put next bit into the MSB position
        value <<= 1

    print


def main():
    sendValue(0x3001)
    sendValue(12289)
    sendValue(0x123f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

**output**

0x3001 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0x3001 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0x123f 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Note that Python has a built-in `bin()` function to convert integers to bit strings:

```
>>> bin(0x3001)
'0b11000000000001'
>>> bin(0xfed)
'0b111111101101'
```

But if you don't want to use `bin()` for some reason, there are other  ways to do it that are more compact than my earlier code. Eg, shifting `value` to the left and masking it with `& 1`, like this:

```
def sendValue(value):
    print hex(value),
    print ' '.join([str(value >> i & 1) for i in range(16, -1, -1)])
```

Answer (score 2):

You got this error because the [hex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) function returns string. Hexadecimal, binary, decimal are only representations of the integer value. 12289 and 0x3001 is the same, So you can just do that:

```
def main():
    sendValue(0x3001)
    sendValue(12289)

    # Or convert string to int if you need 
    sendValue(int(hex(12289), 16))
```